# How do I convert MathML characters to XML in texmath?

Tags: conversion, input-encodings, xml, mathml

I'm in the process of converting LaTeX to MathML in PHP. `texmath` is the command line tool through which the conversion process can be done.

Latex file:

```
\mathbf{f} = (f_{1},
f_{2})^{\prime}
```

test.php:

```
shell_exec('echo "password" | sudo -S /root/.cabal/bin/texmath latexfile > outputfile');
```

If I run this PHP file through the command line, it generates the desired output file which is below.

Command line: `php test.php`

```
 <math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mstyle mathvariant="bold">
      <mi></mi>
    </mstyle>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mo stretchy="false" form="prefix">(</mo>
    <msub>
      <mi>f</mi>
      <mn>1</mn>
    </msub>
    <mo>,</mo>
    <msub>
      <mi>f</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <msup>
      <mo stretchy="false" form="postfix">)</mo>
      <mo>′</mo>
    </msup>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

When I run this PHP file through the browser I am getting an output file like this:

```
<math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mstyle mathvariant="bold">
      <mi>
```

It ignores all the mathtype characters. Why is it gives desired output only through the command line but not through the browser? When I open these two files in the editor it displays 'UTF-8'. Is this a character encoding issue? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is I suspect mostly off topic for this site. The bold f you show is

```
U+1d41f MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL F
```

Which is the right character. As posted on this web site it is correctly encoded and served
as UTF-8 encoded data but we can't tell what your web server is doing.

Make sure the php file is serving the data as utf-8 not iso-8859-1 or any other encoding.
PHP questions are definitely off topic here so if you need help with that you could use the php tag on stack overflow.